# How to use information from one winform in another

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm developing a program that has a homescreen with a button to create a new simulation, that opens a new form called Simulation.
This simulation has two user controls and to use the information from the form in the user controls, i created an instance in the form

```
public static Simulation simulation = new();
public Simulation()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    simulation = this;      
}
```

But if I want to go back to my homescreen and create a new simulation and keep the first one working, I'm not able to use this first one because my instance always receives the new form. How can I fix this?

I tried to create a list with all my Simulation forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables and objects as arguments to a new instance of a form using the parameters of the form's constructor.

```
Form1 newForm = new Form1("some string", 12345);
newForm.Show();
    
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(String passedString, int passedInt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String myString = passedString;
        int myInt = passedInt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good design, but you can use [FindForm()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.findform?view=netframework-4.7.2&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.FindForm)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.7.2)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) to get a reference to the Form that contains your UserControl:

```
public partial class SomeUserControl : UserControl
{

    Simulation simulation = null;

    public SomeUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (simulation == null)
        {
            simulation = this.FindForm() as Simulation;
        }
        
        if (simulation != null)
        {
            label1.Text = simulation.GetTextBoxValue();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the public GetTextBoxValue() method in the main Simulation form:

```
public partial class Simulation : Form
{
    public Simulation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String GetTextBoxValue()
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }

}
```

This will correctly find the instance of Simulation that contains the UserControl, even when multiple instances of Simulation are displayed at the same time.